# BS3 - Collapsible navbar with another collapsible navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make this navbar collapsible. The header should collapse all items and then the first item should collapse the other 3 items. Right now, when I click the header, the navbar collapses and shows again immediately after that. Can you point me out?

```
<div id="body" class="container">
  <section id="navBar" class="col-md-3 navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header primary">
      <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" href="#">navigation</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">payment transactions</a></li>
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#">payment transactions</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">transaction notes</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">slow transactions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems in my code. This is the resolution:

```
<section class="col-md-3 navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="#navbar" class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse">navigation</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse in" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">payment transactions</a></li>
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#">payment transactions</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">transaction notes</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#">slow transactions</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```